# The Sandbox will need extra attention

Tags: discussion

Today I discovered what I can only describe as the juvenile nonsense surrounding Monica Cellio's dismissal as a moderator.  I've spent hours wading through it and almost coming to tears over it.  No one likes seeing an associate they've come to respect and admire be treated like dirt — especially over something as ephemeral as the political issue d'jour.  As I read, I felt sickened.  I have nothing against people of any gender or gender-preference, but ever since I loaned my support to the same-sex-marriage movement, I have become increasingly disillusioned by the LGBT political engine.  And in my opinion, Monica was run over by that engine.

I have decided that I'm done with Stack Exchange.  I posted a longer version of this announcement in frustration [over on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334500/kings-farmers-and-moderators).  In the grand scheme of things, it won't matter much, with possibly one exception.

I was hosting the Sandbox (i.e., I'm the user who created the latest Sandbox).  Before my move to Montana I was very active supporting it, which is natural since as the "OP" for the current box I was notified of everything that went on in it.  If there's no way to transfer that "ownership" to someone else, then everyone will need to remember to visit it regularly and help out the new users.

I have greatly enjoyed participating here.  Honestly, I'm going to miss it.  But SE has become something I can no longer support.

My thanks to everyone.

Comment: So long, and thanks for all the fish.

Comment: Have similar feelings and would also like to express my appreciation for your efforts on SE.  I'm monitoring SE for a positive resolution of this (management) mess, but I honestly don't expect one, which means I'm also effectively done with SE.

Comment: Thanks for all you did for this community.  What SE has done, both the firing and then the abusive and libelous personal attacks afterward, is disgusting.  I am saddened that they care so little for the communities we have built here, that they are content to act disrespectfully and without regard for the communities they are damaging.  About the Sandbox, maybe someone else can open a new iteration now?

Comment: +1 and absolutely spot on re the political machine.   It is a culture destroyer, and even long ago I lamented how the LGBetc folks let themselves be taken in by it.  But I digress. You will be very much missed! Who knows, perhaps you'll find yourself in another worldbuilding forum somewhere and we can catch up!

Comment: I guess I'll have to take my overtaking you in the annual league as read then. Bon voyage, and perhaps we'll meet again on the other side.

Comment: I should note that they now appear to have come up with [a proper apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps?cb=1)

Comment: @Separatrix, it shall also be noted that when someone is punished without following the rules, it is common practice to lift the punishment and apology.

Comment: @L.Dutch yep, I await Monica's report of what they have to say in private before I make any further judgement

Comment: I've only been on this site a short while but its been great reading your answers and occasionally getting to "work" with you on the sandbox. Good luck

Comment: Pity it had to end like this. I'll see if I can do something about the Sandbox.Or of not me, someone else I'm sure will step in to continue your good work. A quick look shows it's looking full or close to. You were "increasingly disillusioned by the LGBT political engine. And in my opinion, Monica was run over by that engine." More like bad managerial practice. Hair-trigger, shoot-first decision-making. Studies show the faster decisions are made the more likely they are to be wrong. This and good old Institutional rear-covering. Seen it before. Too often.